# Echo/Pipe command output to Serial line

Tags: linux, command-line, serial-port, arduino

I have a serial device running on 115200 baud at /dev/ttyUSB0. I need to Pipe the output of a command to it. I Need somthing like:

```
command-that-gives-stdout | command-that-puts-stdin-to-serial --baud 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Thanks Ahead for your help!

*Additional info:* 
I have a grbl Sheild runing off of an arduino. It controlls a CNC machine. I Can send GCode to the arduino via the serial connection (/dev/ttyUSB0 running on 115200 baud). I normally send gcode via the arduino ide's serial monitor. I have Several python files for generating gcode, and they output to the stdout. I could just copy&paste the gcode, but a lot of people that will be using it may get confused by this.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following command should work:

```
( stty raw speed 115200 >&2; echo -ne 'output-string' ) >/dev/ttyUSB0 <&1
```

Note:

- this launches a shell with input and output redirected to your output device;
- input needs redirection because `stty` works on the standard input device, while its diagnostic output should still be directed to the launching terminal;
- `stty raw` stops extraneous characters being added to the output;
- `echo -n` stops the implicit new-line at the end of the string, while `echo -e` allows bask-slashed escape sequences to produce non-printable characters if your device requires it;
- and a subshell is needed so that `/dev/ttyUSB0` isn't closed and reopened, which may reset its settings.

Do not redirect standard error: you don't want error messages sent to the device!

I have tested this on `/dev/tty1` and it seems to work, but I don't have a serial device to verify it completely. I needed to be in a root shell for the command to work, but your permissions may allow it from a user shell.

Comment: would this work piping from another program? this looks very similar to a question i currently have a bounty on. https://superuser.com/questions/1300782/canoga-perkins-password-recovery-brute-forcing-via-com-port

Comment: By another program, do you mean something which will generate output strings instead of `echo` (though I don't understand where the piping comes in)? If so, yes, of course. Without testing, which I can't easily do now, I can't be sure if you can read responses, which wasn't a requirement of the question. You'll need to try it.

Comment: the program i had in mind was crunch in kali linux. where you can pipe it to other programs using "crunch 4 4 abcd | aircrack-ng *.cap" for instance. but instead of piping it to a program sending the output through a serial connection. i'm open to any suggestions. i believe you can also output it to a file if that makes this easier?

Comment: You could use a sub-subshell or command grouping `{ ...; }`, but it's probably easier to replace the `echo` command with a function or script name, and do whatever you need to within that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. If it works I'll send you a message to claim the bounty on my question!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply directing stdout to the /dev/ttyUSB0 (command-that-gives-stdout > /dev/ttyUSB0)? I would think that the OS would handle any buffering and baud rate conversion for you.